# Does the ‘e’ from ‘-yne’ get dropped in compounds of higher functional groups?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, alcohols

What is the way of representing a triple bond in a compound of a higher functional group, like alcohol? Does the ‘e’ from ‘-yne’ get dropped like in the case of the ‘-ene’ suffix?

For example, would the following compound be named **3-methylpent-3-en-2-yn-1,4-diol** or **3-methylpent-3-en-2-yne-1,4-diol** according to IUPAC nomenclature?

[image: unsaturated diol]

Comment: You made an error in counting, otherwise seems OK, so I dunno what you were unsure of...

Comment: I would call it 3-methylpent-3-en-1-yne-1,4-diol

Comment: I was unsure if it should yne or yn since ene becomes en. @Mithoron

Comment: The compound also possesses *cis–trans* isomerism, so you might want to include *E–Z* notation in the name, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitutive names are formed by adding a suffix such as ‘al’, ‘ol’, ‘yl’, ‘carbaldehyde’, ‘carboxylic acid’, etc., to the name of a parent hydride, with elision of the final letter ‘e’ of the parent hydride, if any, before ‘a’, ‘i’, ‘o’, ‘u’, and ‘y’.

The corresponding rule in *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*) reads as follows.

> **P-16.7.1** Vowels are systematically elided as follows:
>
> (a) the terminal letter ‘e’ in names of parent hydrides or endings ‘ene’ and ‘yne’
> when followed by a suffix or ‘en’ ending beginning with ‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’, ‘u’,
> or ‘y’;

Accordingly, the correct name for the compound that is given in the question is **(3*Z*)-3-methylpent-3-en-1-yne-1,4-diol** since ‘yne’ is not followed by ‘a’, ‘e’, ‘i’, ‘o’, ‘u’,
or ‘y’.

Similar examples that can be found in the Blue Book are 2-methylpent-1-en-4-yn-3-ol
and undeca-2,4,7-trien-9-yne-1,11-diol.